# How to set Session variable on text box's on change event in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to update my session variables on textbox's onchange event, without page reload
How to do that.?? thanks!

Comment: I see you've tagged `ajax`, so you are on the right track. Go ahead and look at `$('input[type=text]').change` and `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use on `blur`, that way it wont set the variable everytime the user types, only when he clicks somewhere else....

```
$('textbox').blur(function(){
  var thevalue = $(this).val();

 $.ajax({
    url:'yoururl.php',
    type: "post",
    data:{"value":thevalue},
    dataType:"html",
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    } 
 });
});
```

THen in your php...

```
<?php
   $_SESSION['yoursessionkey'] = $_POST['value'];
   echo "success";
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

You must use `ajax` for it, on `on change event` of textbox like,

```
$('textbox').on('change',function(){
   $.ajax({
        url:'yoururl.php',
        data:{data},
        success:function(){
            alert('success');
        } 
   });
});
```

Comment: I would also include how to add a session variable. Primarily `document.cookie` received from `yoururl.php`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by combination of javascript and PHP.
Make a function() and insert PHP code in it.

Pass the current argument as in session variable in javascript function..

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#field").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url: "http://yourserver.com/ajax.php",
                data: { value: $("#field").val() }
               });
    });
});
</script>
...
<input type="text" id="field" />
```

And in `ajax.php`:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['var'] = $_GET['value'];
?>
```